# bash compare the numeric value of multiple columns

Tags: bash

i have a variable which it output yileds 2 columns:
    echo "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET"

```
A 256
B 256
```

My gloal is basically to compare the 2 numbers and print a massage

somthing like :if they match : Success: A(256) is  euqal to B(256)

or  Error: A(256) is not euqal to B(256) if there is  the numbers are not euqal

My code is:

```
while IFS= read -r i;do
        SIZE=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $2}')
        SOCKET=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $1}')
        if [[ "$SOCKET" = "A" ]] ; then
                SOCKET_A="$SIZE"
        elif [[ "$SOCKET" = "B" ]] ; then
               SOCKET_B="$SIZE"
        fi

        if [[ $SOCKET_A -ne $SOCKET_B]];then
            echo "error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B"
        elif [[ $SOCKET_A -eq $SOCKET_B]];then
            cho "success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B"
        fi
done <<< "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET"
```

the code doesn't yields any output ,anyway there is properly shorter and more elegant way

Comment: you have a typo in the last `elif`: is *echo*; run your script with: `bash -x VALID_PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT` to see what bash is actually comparing

Answer (score 0):

```
input="A 256\nB 256"
arr=($(echo -e "$input"))
if [[ "${arr[1]}" -eq "${arr[3]}" ]]
then
    echo "success: ${arr[0]}(${arr[1]}) is equal to ${arr[2]}(${arr[3]})"
else
    echo "error: ${arr[0]}(${arr[1]}) is not equal to ${arr[2]}(${arr[3]})"
fi
```

Replace the `input` variable by your input and this script outputs either

```
success: A(256) is equal to B(256)
```

for two same numbers or

```
error: A(257) is not equal to B(256)
```

for two different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty straightforward solution I ended up with:

```
line1=$(echo "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET" | awk 'NR == 1')
line2=$(echo "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET" | awk 'NR == 2')

key1=$(echo "$line1" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
value1=$(echo "$line1" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

key2=$(echo "$line2" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
value2=$(echo "$line2" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

if [[ $value1 -eq $value2 ]]; then
    echo "Success: $key1($value1) is equal to $key2($value2)"
else
    echo "Error: $key1($value1) is not equal to $key2($value2)" 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**What is wrong with your code?:**

your code "corrected" would be:

```
SIZE_TO_SOCKET=$(printf '41203235360a42203235360a' | xxd -p -r)

while IFS= read -r i;do
        SIZE=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $2}')
        SOCKET=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $1}')
        if [[ "$SOCKET" = "A" ]] ; then
                SOCKET_A="$SIZE"
        elif [[ "$SOCKET" = "B" ]] ; then
               SOCKET_B="$SIZE"
        fi

        if [[ $SOCKET_A -ne $SOCKET_B ]] ; then
                echo "error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B"
        elif [[ $SOCKET_A -eq $SOCKET_B ]] ; then
                echo "success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B"
        fi  
done <<< "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET"
```

you needed spaces in different places like this one `$SOCKET_B ]] ; then` (your original code is `$SOCKET_B]];then`)

the output of your "corrected" code is:

```
error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B
success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B
```

if you use `bash -x YOUR_SCRIPT`, you get:

```
++ printf 41203235360a42203235360a
++ xxd -p -r
+ SIZE_TO_SOCKET='A 256
B 256'
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
++ echo 'A 256'
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ SIZE=256
++ echo 'A 256'
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ SOCKET=A
+ [[ A = \A ]]
+ SOCKET_A=256
+ [[ 256 -ne '' ]]
+ echo 'error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B'
error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
++ echo 'B 256'
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ SIZE=256
++ echo 'B 256'
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ SOCKET=B
+ [[ B = \A ]]
+ [[ B = \B ]]
+ SOCKET_B=256
+ [[ 256 -ne 256 ]]
+ [[ 256 -eq 256 ]]
+ echo 'success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B'
success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
```

read that carefully; you have an error in your logic.

this could be the corrected version of your code:

```
SIZE_TO_SOCKET=$(printf '41203235360a42203235360a' | xxd -p -r)

while IFS= read -r i;do
        SIZE=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $2}')
        SOCKET=$(echo "$i"|awk '{print $1}')
        if [[ "$SOCKET" = "A" ]] ; then
                SOCKET_A="$SIZE"
        elif [[ "$SOCKET" = "B" ]] ; then
               SOCKET_B="$SIZE"
        fi
done <<< "$SIZE_TO_SOCKET"

if [[ $SOCKET_A -ne $SOCKET_B ]] ; then
        echo "error: SOCKET_A is not equal to SOCKET_B"
elif [[ $SOCKET_A -eq $SOCKET_B ]] ; then
        echo "success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B"
fi
```

the output is:

```
success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B
```

and if you use `bash -x YOUR_CORRECTED_SCRIPT`, you get:

```
++ printf 41203235360a42203235360a
++ xxd -p -r
+ SIZE_TO_SOCKET='A 256
B 256'
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
++ echo 'A 256'
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ SIZE=256
++ echo 'A 256'
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ SOCKET=A
+ [[ A = \A ]]
+ SOCKET_A=256
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
++ echo 'B 256'
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ SIZE=256
++ echo 'B 256'
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ SOCKET=B
+ [[ B = \A ]]
+ [[ B = \B ]]
+ SOCKET_B=256
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
+ [[ 256 -ne 256 ]]
+ [[ 256 -eq 256 ]]
+ echo 'success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B'
success: SOCKET_A is  equal to SOCKET_B
```